# What's the use of ~ in summarise_ function?

Tags: r, summarize

I'm using dplyr's summarise_ function and became curious about the use of ~.

for example,

```
summarise_(school, .dots = list(~ mean(PE), ~ mean(Math), ~n()))
```

gives me the result of means of 2 variables and the number of observations. But why should I use ~ in front of each function?  I don't need it when using summarise function, so want to know what it's for!

Comment: Read https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thank you for that link!  I needed that too.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Hey thanks for the link. I read that, but still don't get what the ~ sign really means, or in other words, if not in summarise_ function can I still use that sign for what kind of reason. I've only used it in constructing models.. for a simple  example y ~ x1 + x2. Well maybe that ~ in summarise_ does the similar thing?

Comment: It has got something to do with non-standard evaluation. In the `dplyr` package, most functions use non-standard evaluation. This enables you to address variables in a data frame without quoting them (e.g. `data %>% filter(variable1 > 0)`). This makes the code more readable but it can also cause problems. Therefore, all (or at least some) of the functions in the package come in a "standard evaluation" version, where the name is appended by an underscore (`summarise` vs. `summarise_`). With these functions you need to quote the variable names and `~` is a form of quoting.

Comment: @ikop Thanks for your clear explanation! So in summary, ~ is to support using formulas in the SE version, which is '_ appended' of NSE version's functions such as summarise(), filter(), etc. Hope I correctly understood your words.

Comment: The tilde here has little to do with the tilde in the formulas used for models. Here, it basically just explicitly tells the function `summarise_` that `PE` and `Math` are variables in the data frame `school`.

Comment: @ikop Oh I understood. It was kind of confusing for me cause I've used quotes when indicating variables, but after your comments I tried some codes to find out: 
school %>% summarise_(.dots = list(~mean(PE), ~mean(Math))) is same with school %>% summarise_(.dots = list("mean(PE)", "mean(Math)")),  and works same for other functions. When using select_(), I can use both tilde and quotes to indicate variables. Thanks ikop.